# Dates and times with no repeated digits?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I have a digital clock that shows the date and time like this:
$$
\mathsf{YYYY-(M)M-(D)D\qquad (H)H:MM \; [:SS]}
$$
That is, the seconds display is optional, and if the month or day or hour is single-digit, it won't display a leading zero.  This is a nice year, $2013$, because all the digits are different... that hasn't happened since $1987$.  What's more, if I turn off the seconds display, there are some times coming up this year that use nine of the ten digits with no repeats.

That's *pretty* good, but it looks like I'll have to wait a long time to see all ten digits with no repeats, and I wanted to do even better.  So I custom-ordered a clock that uses base eleven (i.e., it shows the same year, month, day, hour, minute, and second as the other clock, but using base eleven -- it doesn't use $66$-minute hours or anything like that).  I'm waiting patiently for that one to show all *eleven* digits with no repeats.

- When's the next time (this year) we'll see nine distinct digits?
- When's the next time we'll see all ten distinct digits?
- When's the next time the base-eleven clock will show all eleven distinct digits?